Create user with data about their interests
Im currently working on a project that is similar to a social network, im in the phase of creating the database and when the users are creating their accounts it will have like common data (name,email,password...etc) but I want to have their interests (music, books, hiking, fitness, etc) these will be static fields that they can mark and depending on those interest the website will recomend specific events. How could I do this?
Im using mongoose and this is the model i got
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
          throw new Error("Email is invalid");
        }
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 7,
      validate(value) {
        if (value.toLowerCase().includes("password")) {
          throw new Error("The password cant include 'password' ");
        }
      },
    },
    age: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
      validate(value) {
        if (value < 0) {
          throw new Error("The age must be greater than 0");
        }
      },
    },
    interest: {
      type: ?, //These part
    },
    tokens: [
      {
        token: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);

I thougth about making all the values of my interests inside my user and depending on what he marks ill put these interests in true but i dont know if it is a better way of doing this

Which ways are "better" is very much a matter of opinion.  If you have some specific criteria you are trying to meet, edit the question to specify those specifically.
